# PhalconPHP - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, phalcon

I am trying to make a AngularJS SPA with PhalconPHP as backend. So far I setup PhalconPHP and Phalcon tools and did a couple of tutorials on their website.
I just cannot seem to find a good example on how to make a API for Angular to connect with. There is [this one](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html) on their website but I don't really think it's the right approach for a big AngularJS application.

I kinda like the way controllers are linked to the a route without having a route file in place but it would be nice to make groups in which routes can be placed.

Example:
I would have the following route:

http://example.com/api/foo/bar

In which api is just a the part of the rout which is always present.
Foo should be the part that can seperate the this part of the api from other parts.
Bar should be the controller.

Does anyone have a uptodate recommendation for a AngularJS application following this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Phalcon matches routes on `/:controller/:action` but you can easily make it to match `/api/:controller/:action`:

```
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
$router->add(
"/api/:controller/:action/:params",
    array(
        "controller" => 1,
        "action"     => 2,
        "params"     => 3,
    )
);
```

You can add to route matching other parameters, like `:module` or `:namespace` to break down you code even more: [Defining routes](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#defining-routes)